# Select tag in php

Tags: php, html

I have a select tag with two options. I need to keep the selected  value from a database. This is my code.

```
<?php   
$from=$row["Member_From"]; 
echo '<select name="status'. $row['user_name'] .'">  
<option value="active" name="active">Active</option>  
<option value="inactive"name="inactive">Inactive</option> 
</select>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to put default selection, just add 'selected' property to one of option tags - it may look like this:

```
<?php   
$from=$row["Member_From"]; 

$isActive = true; // Get from somewhere

echo '<select name="status'. $row['user_name'] .'">  
<option value="active" name="active" '.($isActive?'selected':'').'>Active</option>  
<option value="inactive" name="inactive"  '.($isActive?'':'selected').'>Inactive</option> 
</select>';
```